# Unknown error while connecting

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am trying to learn OOP for PHP by following a lynda.com video.  The problem is they are using MySQL and I am trying to use MySQLi.  I am using xampp set up on my local system with Windows 7.  I have a config file that contains the following:

```
// Database Constants
defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define("DB_SERVER", "127.0.0.1");
defined('DB_USER')   ? null : define("DB_USER", "gallery");
defined('DB_PASS')   ? null : define("DB_PASS", "phpOTL123");
defined('DB_NAME')   ? null : define("DB_NAME", "photo_gallery");
```

then I have a database.php file that is to do the connecting:

```
require_once("config.php");

class MySQLDatabase {

private $conn;

function __construct() {
  $this->open_connection();
}
public function open_connection() { 
   $this->conn = mysqli_connect('.', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS','DB_NAME');
  // $this->conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "gallery", "phpOTL123");
   if (!$this->conn) {
       die("Database connection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error($this->conn));
   } else {
       $db_select = mysqli_select_db($this->conn, "photo_gallery");
       if(!$db_select) {
           die("Database selection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error($this->conn));
       }
   }
}
```

as it is it will not connect, but when I try it not using the constants it will.  I am getting the following error:

```
Unknown errror while connecting in C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 12.
```

Line 12 is

```
$this->conn = mysqli_connect('.', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS','DB_NAME');
```

I have used MySQLi before in a separate file buy did not use the constants and had no issues.   I have tried having them in the same file (database.php) and still got the same error.  I have also looked at the other questions that are similar to this and they recommended using

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "config.php");
```

but this still did not help.  Am I missing something with the constants?

Comment: if your database in your localhost, set the host to localhost: `mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS','DB_NAME');` if not set the proper host.

Comment: I had used 127.0.0.1, and then read in the php manual that by using the '.' it would speed up the connection time.  almost 1 second with 127.0.0.1 and almost instantly with '.'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the constant's name as a string, not its value, change it to the following:

```
$this->conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

using constant don't need quotes.

Comment: That was it along with keeping the require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "config.php");!!  Thanks for the assistance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The hostname should be a FQDN or an IP Address. Also, there shouldn't be any `'`s enclosing the constants. Please change the line to any of them below:

```
$this->conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$this->conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

Or you need to use the already defined constants!

```
$this->conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```